# Generating function of the stopped simple random walk

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $\varepsilon_i$ be independent random variables such that $\mathbb{P}(\varepsilon_i = \pm 1)= 1/2$ and denote $W_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\varepsilon_i$. That is, $W_n$ is the simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ started at $0$. Denote by $\tau_k$ the hitting time of $k\in \mathbb{N}$ (the smallest time $t$ when $W_t=x$). I am interested in the simple random walk that is stopped if it hits $k$. So let us define
$$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{\min(\tau_k, n)}\varepsilon_{i}.$$

**Question.** Does the generating function $f_h(t)=\mathbb{E}e^{hS_n}$ have a simple analytical expression and maybe it is known?

Comment: In $f_h(t)=\mathbb{E}e^{hS_n}$, what is $h$?  Did you intend $f_{n,k}(t)=\mathbb{E}e^{t S_n}$ as the moment generating function?